# Symbolic Transpose on WxMaxima

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

How could I apply the transpose operator after it has returned the nominal expression?

I'm working with some symbolic matrix equations, and I have to deal with the transpose, after that I need to substitute some matrices with real values, the symbolic matrices are symbols declared as nonscalar like this:

```
declare(A,nonscalar);
declare(B,nonscalar);
declare(a,scalar);
equation:transpose(A*a).B=0
subst([A=transpose(matrix([1,2,3])),B=transpose(matrix([3,2,1]))],equation)
```

the result is:

```
(transpose(matrix([1],[2],[3])) . matrix([3],[2],[1]))*a=0
```

but I'm expecting something like

```
10*a=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ev(%, nouns)` after the `subst`. Also take a look at the various flags which modify `.` expressions, in particular `dotscrules`. I think `?? dot` and `?? mx` will find most or all of those flags.

Comment: ev(%,nouns) is not working with the transpose, i've checked the flags and I didn't find anything about the transpose

Comment: Well, what I am seeing is that `equation:transpose(A*a).B=0` creates a noun expression; I can see that via `:lisp $%`, what do you see if you try that? After you get `(transpose(matrix([1],[2],[3])) . matrix([3],[2],[1]))*a=0`, what do you see if you enter `:lisp $%` after that? I am working with the Maxima console interface; it is possible that wxMaxima has set some flags to different values. I suggested the `dot` and `mx` flags is that I was thinking the presence of the scalar `a` was playing a role. PS. The noun form of `transpose` is `%TRANSPOSE` in Lisp output as opposed to `$TRANSPOSE`.

Comment: with `equation:transpose(A*a).B=0` I see  `((MEQUAL SIMP)
 ((MTIMES SIMP) $A ((MNCTIMES SIMP) ((%TRANSPOSE SIMP) $a) $b)) 0)` then with `subst([A=transpose(matrix([1,2,3])),B=transpose(matrix([3,2,1]))],equation)` I see `((MEQUAL SIMP)
 ((MTIMES SIMP)
  ((MNCTIMES SIMP)
   ((%TRANSPOSE SIMP)
    (($MATRIX SIMP) ((MLIST SIMP) 1) ((MLIST SIMP) 2) ((MLIST SIMP) 3)))
   (($MATRIX SIMP) ((MLIST SIMP) 3) ((MLIST SIMP) 2) ((MLIST SIMP) 1)))
  $A)
 0)`

Comment: OK, well, I see `%TRANSPOSE` operators in those expressions. I would expect `ev(<whatever>, nouns)` to cause the transpose to be applied to its literal matrix operand.

Comment: I run ev(<expression>,nouns) and failed, but ev(%,nouns) worked nice, thank you